# Starting Point for Time Sheet Calculations JQuery/Ajax/other

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I need to create a bunch of front-end calculations for time. I have searched and searched and can't seem to find any good tutorials or templates to get me pointed in the right direction. I'm wondering if anyone can do just that regarding the following link:

**https://crm.champ.net/timesheet-static**

So here's what I need help with to accomplish. **When the user enters the time & and time out (then time in 2 & time out 2), I need to calculate the total regular hours for that day.**

I've got all the back end PHP/MySQL stuff covered once I can get the values populated, but I assume it's Ajax or JQuery that I'm looking for here and I don't know how to do any of it. Any ideas or links to someone who has already done it?

Comment: You need to do things with date times? like with JavaScript Dates? http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

Comment: It isn't really clear if you're looking for help with DateTime calculations or jQuery/Ajax or both.

Comment: It's the math part I need help with.

Comment: Sorry, I edited the original post to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

In this case we are making a DateTime from a date string like this one "08/18/2014 05:30:PM".

From that page, this is an example to get a proper date time from two of the fields there.
`var time = new Date($('#fdate1').val() +" "+ $('#fti2-1').val())`. fdate1 containing the reference to the date and fti2-2 the reference to the time.

You can then use the DateTime functions that are built into JS.

Reference: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

Some ones to note:

The .getTime() function is used to return the number of milliseconds since midnight Jan 1, 1970.
You could use this to get the difference in two dates.

.getDate() will return the day of the current month in the DateTime.

.setDate() will set the date based on the current month in the DateTime (Example below). Passing in a negative number or a number that over flows the number of days in the month that is currently in the DateTime will advance the DateTime to the next month with the correct number of days based on the overflow.

This same logic can be applied to Minutes, Seconds, ect.

Examples:

```
function differenceInMinutes(timeIn, timeOut) {
  return (timeOut.getTime() - timeIn.getTime()) / 1000 / 60;
  //1000 ms per sec. 60 sec per min
}

function twoWeeksAgo() {
  //gets new DateTime set to current time
  var date = new Date();
  //We get the current day of the month (at time of this post it will return 19).
  //Subtract 14 from that and set that to the current day.
  date.setDate(date.getDate() - 14);
  return date;
  //A value causing the date to be less then 0 (in this case 20 or greater) will cause the date to push back the the last month.
}
```